# How can I use ViewPager to display apps?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

As the title states, how exactly can I use `ViewPager` to display a list of apps. Right now I'm using a `GridView` to display the list of apps on my device and it runs the app upon selection. However I wish to get a similar effect from launchers in the Play Store, the app drawer is split into different views and displays a set number of apps on one page. And when you swipe it goes to the second page and displays more apps.

How can I do this? At the moment I just have a simple `GridView` which can be scrolled up and down,

I have looked all around the internet and i have gotten no answers, I've taken a look at the aosp launchers src on github but it's too complicated to understand.
Thank to whoever answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jake Wharton's Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) in ViewPager to display your content. You can also try [astutez's PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip), it will me more suitable for your requirements. Implementation is very simple, you can also find the [sample](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/tree/master/sample) in the repository.